# AdMob ad won't load and crashes

Tags: swift, sdk, uikit, admob, ads

I have already installed Cocoapods and the Google mobile ads SDK. I've followed everything on the admob get started site and even checked a few youtube videos. All the code seems to be fine but I keep getting these two errors repeatedly in the console;

WF: _WebFilterIsActive returning: NO
WF: _userSettingsForUser : (null)

The ads don't show and the app continues to run but the area where the ad is supposed to be just goes blank. How can I fix this? Been searching around for ages

-Thankyou

Comment: That's like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Honestly , I’ve been looking around for so long but the same error message comes up for various reasons so I’m stuck at the moment

Comment: Are they test ads? Are you using the test id? You won’t get real ads in your app until after it is approved and is in the store for a while.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/admob/ios/test-ads

Comment: Yeah they were test ads and I used the test ID. I figured out what the problem was. I was adding the frame for the ad in override view did layout subviews and I just moved the code out of the functions and into the viewdidload and its working perfectly fine. Im still getting the same error codes but its got nothing to do with mobAds I'm assuming